# I wonder why the TabBarView widget builds twice

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the DefaultTabController widget and the TabBarView widget. When running for the first time, OneScreen screen is built only once. After the build, if you press restart, the build is done twice.

There is a bigger problem here. Similar code is used in my project, and when it is first run, it builds 3 times. After the build, if you press restart, 18 builds are taking place. A build is not a build that calls other widgets. Build the same widget multiple times.

In my opinion, if you find out why the build is done twice after restart, you can solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(initialIndex: 0, vsync: this, length: 4);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: [
            OneScreen(),
            TwoScreen(),
            ThreeScreen(),
            FourScreen(),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            indicator: BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(width: 3.5, color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor))),
            labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),
                iconMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: Text('One', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),
                iconMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: Text('Two', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),
                iconMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: Text('Three', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),
                iconMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: Text('Four', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
// two,three,four screen is same OneScreen
class OneScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OneScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OneScreen> createState() => _OneScreenState();
}

class _OneScreenState extends State<OneScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('one.dart');
    return Center(
      child: Text('One'),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try learn flutter lifecycle https://medium.flutterdevs.com/app-lifecycle-in-flutter-c248d894b830 . build will be call after setstate or didUpdateWidget, build will be appear one or more depend your code